# Each element of InputQueue in TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput> is overwritten whenever a record is read

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

#### Purpose

I'm trying to create a pipeline where I read from a file one bytes record at a time and send it to a `BufferBlock', which append items in the buffer block. This is linked through the trivial LinkTo () method to TransformBlock <byte [], MyObject> which converts each record of bytes into the MyObject object.
Below is the whole method that does all this:

```
    BufferBlock<byte[]> buffer = new BufferBlock<byte[]>();
    TransformBlock<byte[], MyObject> transform = new TransformBlock<byte[], MyObject>(bytes =>
    {
        return FromBytesTOMyObject(bytes);
    });

    private void ReadFileAndAppend()
    {
        buffer.LinkTo(transform, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("C:\\Users\\MyUser\\myFile.raw",FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read));                                  
        int count;
        byte[] record = new byte[4000];

        // Post more messages to the block.
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while ((count = br.Read(record, 0, record.Length)) != 0)
                await buffer.SendAsync(record);
            buffer.Complete();
        });
        transform.Completion.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("");
```

Below the method that is called inside the TransformBlock:

```
static public MyObject FromBytesToMyObject(byte[] record)
    {
        MyObject object = new MyObject();
        object.counter = BitConverter.ToInt32(record, 0);
        object.nPoints = BitConverter.ToInt32(record, 4);

        for (int i = 0; i < object.nPoints; i++)
        {
            int index = i * 4;
            object.A[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(record, index + 8);
        }
        return object;
    }
```

as can be seen from the FromBytesToMyObject () methodthere is a counter inside each record read. **So each record never has a counter equal to another record** (I also checked through a byte reader like HxD)

#### Problem

With this setting I thought that the reading and interpretation of the file took place smoothly. But going into debugging and inserting a breakpoint in the "while" after reading about 50 records or more, I noticed that in TransformBlock's OutputQueue
groups of records with the same counter are queued, and therefore identical records.

Example:

Exact queue considering only the counters:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

Queue that I actually see in OutputQueue: 1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5 ....

Can you explain to me where I'm wrong?

Comment: @EugeneSh. IMO it is C# . I have edited the tags

Comment: The `while (br.BaseStream.Position != br.BaseStream.Length)` line looks sketchy. The completion of a stream-reading loop is usually determined by the `reader.Read` method returning a zero. Using a externally provided `byte[]` buffer looks even sketchier. God knows where else this buffer could be used concurrently...

Comment: Without a [mcve] it's impossible to provide a good answer. That said, from the description it seems almost certain that you are using the same reference-type object instance with each block, and so of course when you modify that object, all other references to the same object show the same modification.

Comment: As a side note, the `BufferBlock` is probably redundant. You could feed the `TransformBlock` directly, since it has its own internal input queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reusing the same `byte[] record` over and over again, without any thread-safety considerations. No wonder that things are going south fast. If you want to ensure the correctness of the whole operation, you must use a different buffer each time:

```
while (true)
{
    var record = new byte[4000];
    var count = binaryReader.Read(record, 0, record.Length);
    if (count == 0) break;
    Array.Resize(ref record, count);
    await buffer.SendAsync(record);
}
buffer.Complete();
```

If you also care about the performance and don't want to overburden the garbage collector, you should look at the [`ArrayPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1) class. But be careful because this class offers new ways to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: what is the `Array.Resize(ref record, count);` for, if the variable is reassigned every time?

Comment: @NickMan the last `Read` will most probably read less than 4000 bytes, so you'll need some way to communicate the exact number of bytes read when passing the buffer to the `TransformBlock`. You'll have to either resize the buffer, or pass the count along with the buffer to the block.